# When a question is nominated for deletion?

Tags: discussion, support, deletion, privileges

These days I've looked a little for the questions eligible for deletion, and I'm very confused. How the system chooses amongst the questions which one can be deleted and which one can't?

For instance, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295382/radical-of-an-ideal-i) has 4 downvotes, and it's old enough, however it's not proposed for deletion, while [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009056/let-g-be-a-group-satisfying-a2-1-for-all-a-in-g-show-that-g-is-abelian) it is (well, this is also a duplicate, but I've seen similar questions to the first one which were not nominated for deletion).

Comment: The first one is not closed. 10k users can only vote to delete closed (or on-hold) questions.

Answer (score 8):

A user can vote to delete a question when all of the following hold:

- the users has at least 10.000 points.
- the question is on-hold/closed since at least 48h.
- the question is neither locked nor a duplicate *target.*

For users with at least 20.000 the 48h rule does not apply for questions with low score.

Nobody but moderators (including the community-user) and the author can vote to delete open questions.

(This discussion excludes self-deletions. )

Answer (score 3):

This was basically answered in [Daniel Fischer's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20390/when-a-question-is-nominated-for-deletion#comment78100_20390). Anyway, to get the question answered, I will copy the relevant details from the documentation.

From the description of the privileges you [obtain at 10k](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> You must wait for a question to be closed for **2** days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for [trusted users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) when a post scores **-3** or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please [**flag** it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for community moderator attention.

From [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> **Users with reputation >= 10k** (more precisely, the [“moderator tools” privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools); 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete *questions* that have been [closed/on-hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stack-overflow-how-do-they-work) for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete; [more if the question is popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), but ten votes at most.